# I am getting an error if acc[0] == var[0]: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptabl. how do I fix this?

Tags: python

I am writing a car rental program on python.
In this function I am trying to modify car details which are added in the details.txt file but I am getting an error "if acc[0] == var[0]:TypeError:'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
how do I fix this error ?

```
def modifying():
    global acc        
    exist = False
    mod_file = open("details.txt")
    count = 0
    for s in mod_file:
        var = s.split(",")  # spilt the data into list
        var[2] = var[2].strip()
        if acc[0] == var[0]:
            exist = True
            break
        count += 1
    mod_file.close()

    if exist != True:
        print("!!! Can NOT Find The Data !!!")

    elif exist == True:
        s_list = []
        mod_file = open("details.txt", "r")
        for s in mod_file:
            s = s.strip()
            s_list.append(s)
            mod_file.close

        choice = "Y"
        while choice == "Y":
            print("\n===============================")
            print("---------- MODIFY Cars ----------")
            print("---------------------------------")
            print("Select the details you wish to modify")
            print("1. Type")
            print("2. Manufactured Year")
            print("3. details of the car")
            print("4. car code")
            print("5. Daily price rate ( USD $ )")
            print("6. back")
            while True:
                try:
                    c = int(input("please select a number (1 - 5): "))
                    modify = ["Type", "Manufactured Year", "details of the car", "car code", "Daily price rate ( USD $ )"]
                    if c > 0 and c < 6:
                        new = input("\nType the New " + modify[c - 1] + ":")
                        var[c - 1] = new
                        temp = ",".join(var)
                        s_list[count] = temp
                        mod_file = open("details.txt", "w")
                        mod_file.write("")
                        mod_file.close()

                        count_file = 0
                        for s in range(len(s_list)):
                            mod_file = open("details.txt", "r")
                            for counting in mod_file:
                                count_file += 1
                            mod_file.close()

                            mod_file = open("details.txt", "a")
                            if count_file == 0:
                                mod_file.write(s_list[s])
                            else:
                                mod_file.write("\n")
                                mod_file.write(s_list[s])
                            mod_file.close()

                        print("\nDetails UPDATED")
                        be_exit = input("\nDo you want to modify again? (Y/N): ").upper()
                        if be_exit == "y":
                            choice = "y"
                        else:
                            modifying(acc)
                    elif c == 6:
                        modifying(acc)
                    else:
                        print("\n!!! Incorrect Input !!!\n")
                        continue
                except:
                    print("\n!! NOT a Number !!!\n")
                    continue


modifying()
```

Comment: Avoid using `global`.

Comment: Where did you defined `acc`?

Comment: You have just done ```global acc```, not assigned anything to it. What do you thing ```global acc``` does? Also, ```modifying()``` takes no parameters. But you are providing one.

Comment: How can the error message be any clearer? You have to define a variable named `acc` first. `global` does **not** define a variable.

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `python nameerror` into a search engine?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```py
acc = some_value
def modifying():
    global acc
    exist = False
    mod_file = open("details.txt")
    count = 0
    for s in mod_file:
        var = s.split(",")  # spilt the data into list
        var[2] = var[2].strip()
        if acc[0] == var[0]:
            exist = True
            break
```

In your example you haven't defined the variable acc. Using `global` just say that the variable is a global variable, but you're not assigning a value to it